# HTTP Metadata Requests with WSIT/JAX-WS

Tags: wcf, metadata, jax-ws, java-metro-framework, wsit

I have a problem running a Java (using Metro) client against a .NET STS and secured web service. However, when I run my .NET based client, it always works.

As you probably already know, when a JAX-WS client is ran, it requests metadata from the service during runtime (even though it already has ran wsimport during design time). However, it seems that this runtime metadata request is where my problem is.

The problem that I'm facing is that during the runtime requests of metadata, some WSDL's exported by my WCF service caused the Java client to just 'hang' during the mex requests. When it hangs, it doesn't even get to the point of issuing the RST request.

For example, I can get to a spot where I have 9 [OperationContract] attributes and it works. But when I add a 10th service method, it doesn't work. However, if I remove one of the 9, then it works. I know there isn't a problem with a particular method because I can mix and match and the same pattern holds.

I can't seem to deduce a pattern or reason for why some WSDL's work and some don't. I strongly doubt there is a limit to the number of service methods. However, could this be a problem with "overall complexity" with the exported WSDL?

Does anyone have any ideas? Have anyone run into this issue before?

If more information is needed, I can glady post it. I'm just trying to keep the initial post a manageable length.

I will also add that I'm running the STS and secured web serivce in .NET 4, and they are based on WIF (so I don't have to worry about security settings). My .NET client is also .NET 4. On the Java side, I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 with Metro 2.1 running Glassfish 3. I've verified that I receive the same issue running on Metro 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [WSDL Requests with Metro/JAX-WS/WSIT During Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315229/wsdl-requests-with-metro-jax-ws-wsit-during-runtime/4674700#4674700) for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example given, there're chances that MaxMessageReceivedSize or MaxStringContentLength limit is reached. Have you tried increasing the values of MaxMessageReceivedSize and MaxStringContentLength for binding? You can try enabling WCF traces, there'd be a warning logged if any such limit is reached.

Comment: thank for you response, but I have no problems retrieving metadata in .NET (either thru adding a service reference or using svcutil directly). My problem is in Java fetching metadata during run-time. I have also created custom mex binding increasing those values you specified and it still doesn't work.